# How can I ensure existence of the WorkingDirectory path within a systemd service file?

Tags: systemd, services

I am using systemd services to keep my NodeJS packages running.

```
[Unit]
Description=MyNodePackage
After=network.target

[Service]
WorkingDirectory=              /home/me/.config/MyNodePackage
ExecStartPre=+/bin/mkdir -p    /home/me/.config/MyNodePackage
ExecStartPre=+/bin/chown me:me /home/me/.config/MyNodePackage
ExecStartPre=+/usr/bin/npm install --global --allow-root --unsafe-perm my-node-package
ExecStart=    /usr/bin/npx my-node-package
Environment=NODE_ENV=production "NODE_OPTIONS=--max_old_space_size=4000"
User=me
Group=me
Restart=on-failure
RestartSec=60s
TimeoutStartSec=5m
PrivateTmp=true

[Install]
WantedBy=multi-user.target
```

I would like to drop in a service file like this and start it with:

```bsh
sudo service myNodePackage start
```

- But starting does fail because `/home/me/.config/MyNodePackage` does not exist yet.
- If I use `WorkingDirectory=-` instead of `WorkingDirectory=`, it does start properly but working directory is not set at all because of the failed existence check, and thus not available in `process.cwd()` in my Node environment. (only for the first time the service is started)
- I would like not to ensure existence of `/home/me/.config/MyNodePackage` outside of the service file to keep it self-managing. But yes, simply doing `mkdir -p /home/me/.config/MyNodePackage && sudo service myNodePackage start` would be a solution.
  Is there a way to do the `WorkingDirectory=` after `ExecStartPre=`, not before? I mean, I only need the proper working directory set for my `ExecStart=`, and not for any of my 3 `ExecStartPre=` calls.